# Autounattend.xml setting internet explorer 11 as default browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am using `Windows 10 Pro Build 15063`.

I would like to set the `IE 11 as default Browser in the Autounattend.xml` (also known as Unattend.xml) after the OS deployment. Does any one knows how to active that?

Thanks for any feedback and cheers

Comment: I try to check the structure of Autounattend.xml file and I find that we can set the default search engine in it but i did not get any way to set IE as default browser in it. Reference: https://www.intowindows.com/download-unattend-xml-for-windows-10/

Comment: Hey Deepak-MSFT

Thanks for Helping me with this. So i will try it differently.

Cheers